# Toggle element styling on click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle the style attribute on click. I'm not trying to change the value of the style attribute, I'd like to actually add and remove the whole style attribute.

So it'd look like this to start with

```
<div class="example" style="background-color:red">
```

and on click it'd go to just

```
<div class="example">
```

and on the next click, it'd be

```
<div class="example" style="background-color:red">
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: 1) Don't use inline styles 2) http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

Answer (score 1):

By using `toggleClass()` you can change the `background-color` property:

```js
$('.example').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red')
})
```

```css
.example {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #adadad;
}

.red {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use inline-styles you can save styles in one variable and then toggle it using `attr()`

```js
var div = $('.example');
var css = div.attr('style')

div.click(function() {
  div.attr('style', div.attr('style') != '' ? '' : css)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" style="background-color:red; color: white;">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) and remove the inline-styling. Below is a simple example for you:

```js
$(".example").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  Something comes here...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class to achieve this effect.

CSS

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="example"></div>
```

JavaScript/JQuery

```
$('.example').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/20v7yuLm/

```js
$('div').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('example');
});
```

```css
.example{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" >
test
</div>
```